# Why aren't State options non-default countries (outside UK) showing for billing address on the contribution page of a webform?

Tags: webform-civicrm, contribution-page, addresses, localisation

Drupal 7.39
CiviCRM 4.5.8
Webform Integration 7.x-4.11

I've got a webform to capture membership info and payments.

To share the address with related contacts, Contact 1's address is captured twice, once in a main details section and again on the final contribution page.

When entering the first address the country and state fields work fine. If a non-uk address is selected the expected state/province fields are available to select. (The organisation already has a number of overseas members).

United Kingdom is the default country in localization settings.

On the contribution section, the uk states appear as default. If Uk is deselected and another country chosen the state field displays only the UK options.

When accessing the related contribution page directly the address fields behave as expected. States list populates dynamically from the chosen country.

The contribution page is configured specifically for use with the webform so no profiles are included the profile tab.

I've tried deselecting uk as default and leaving that for the user to choose. But that meant no states at all were displayed in the state box on the webform.

State/Province is configured as a required field on the webform contribution page so leaving it set to none means payments can't be configured.

As it stands the form can be used for domestic membership sign ups, but cannot be used by prospective overseas members.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Any pointers to settings I need to amend?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi - just a question, is your country field before or after the state/province field?  If it's after it, you might try moving it to before the state/province field... what I've found, at least on regular Civi profiles, is that the country field needs to be first so that the form can populate the state/province after the country is selected.  Not sure if CIvi webforms are the same but it might be worth a try. ~ Lesley

Comment: Thanks Leslie,

In both cases the Country field appears first. :)

Comment: Have you checked for javascript errors?

Comment: No.

Do you have a link with instructions on how to do that?

Comment: Just googled javascript errors and realised I can do that in browser.

Thanks for the pointer! I'll come back and look at it with fresh eyes on Monday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too on the main Civi911.com checkout form, and then I was all the more sheepish when it turns out the issue was reported by my coworker Tyrell for one of our clients!  It's a bug in 7.x-4.11 and earlier: https://www.drupal.org/node/2516936

If you upgrade, the state/province in the billing address should update along with the country.

Comment: Hah!

Spent ages searching with the term civicrm to find anyone that posted the same issue.

If only I'd added the drupal term may have found that post sooner. 

Thanks Andrew. Will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Yup, all working as expected. Thanks @andrew-hunt for the pointer, much appreciated.